# Crashes when using UIView.animate in the removeFromSuperview() method

Tags: swift

I have a view that I'm adding to the VC, and the view has a button inside it. When the button is clicked, the removeFromSuperview method is called.

```
@objc func confirmAction()
    
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}

override func removeFromSuperview() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.bgView.alpha = 0.1
        self.bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.height, self.bottomView.frame.width, self.bottomView.frame.height)
    } completion: { finish in
        self.bgView.alpha = 0.1
        self.bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.height, self.bottomView.frame.width, self.bottomView.frame.height)
        super.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Instead, I received the following error log

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000951d5b40fb50

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c20 objc_msgSend + 32
1  UIKitCore                      0x4e7c -[UIView bounds] + 32
2  ZYLight                        0x2e0a20 closure #2 in ZYAddDeviceStepView.removeFromSuperview() + 4301179424
3  ZYLight                        0x775fc thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Bool) -> () + 4298651132 (<compiler-generated>:4298651132)
4  UIKitCore                      0x104278c __UIVIEW_IS_EXECUTING_ANIMATION_COMPLETION_BLOCK__ + 36
5  UIKitCore                      0xd1280 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 636
6  UIKitCore                      0xd01dc -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 436
7  UIKitCore                      0xcf8fc -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 196
8  UIKit                          0xb1848 -[UIViewAnimationStateAccessibility animationDidStop:finished:] + 172
9  QuartzCore                     0x12dfc CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 232
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x3f88 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x127f4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x12444 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
13 CoreFoundation                 0x9a6c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
14 CoreFoundation                 0x7c02c __CFRunLoopRun + 2036
15 CoreFoundation                 0x80eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
16 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
17 UIKitCore                      0x3a1668 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
18 UIKitCore                      0x3a12cc UIApplicationMain + 340
19 libswiftUIKit.dylib            0x35308 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 104
20 ZYLight                        0x86c4 main + 4298196676 (ZYLightMeshProtocol.swift:4298196676)
```

Can someone help me see what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: You’re calling `super.removeFromSuperview()` that should probably not be called on super but self.bgView

Comment: What's the value of `finish` in this case?

Comment: Why is the completion block calling the same code as the animation block? Remove those first two lines from the completion block.